# Перезапуск SVG анимации через удаление animateTransform

Tags: javascript, css, css3, svg, анимация

Всем привет. Возникла проблема с `svg` анимацией. Мне нужно чтобы `js` останавливал анимацию круга ( для этого я удаляю тег `<animateTransform>`), а затем возобновлял ее ( возвращаю тег обратно), и анимация начиналась либо с начала, либо, что еще лучше, **с того места где остановилась.**

Но при возвращении тега анимация продолжается с того момента, где был бы круг если бы я не удалял анимацию. Собственно вопрос в том, что я делаю неправильно.

Заранее спасибо!

```js
const circle = document.getElementsByTagName('circle')[0],
  animate = `<animateTransform  
          attributeName="transform" 
          type="translate" 
          values="0;460;0"
          dur="3s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"/>`;
let b = true;
setInterval(() => {
  b ? circle.innerHTML = '' : circle.innerHTML = animate;
  b = !b
}, 1000);
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
    <circle r="20" cy="20" cx="20" fill="#ce3400">
          <animateTransform  
          attributeName="transform" 
          type="translate" 
          values="0;460;0"
          dur="3s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Вам нужна пауза после прохождения элемента(круг) до определённой точки (0-460;пауза;460-0;пауза и т.д.) ?

Comment: @St1myL  мне нежно, чтобы анимация закончилась, а потом (после нажатия на чекбокс например) я ее перезапустил через js

Comment: Тогда мой вариант не подойдёт, думал нужно в анимацию паузы поставить

Comment: @Dantessss добавлен новый ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Добавляем кнопки "GO" и "STOP" старта и остановки анимации. На
  которые вешаем события `onclick='start()'` и  `onclick='pause()'`

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
 <g transform="translate(-10,80)">
      <g id="gO1" onclick='start()'>
        <rect x="45" y="85" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="#0080B8" stroke="dodgerblue" />
        <text x="62" y="102" font-size="16" fill="yellow">GO</text>
      </g>
      <g onclick='pause()'>
        <rect x="110" y="85" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="crimson" stroke="red" />
        <text x="120" y="102" font-size="16" fill="yellow">STOP</text>
      </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

- Добавляем в  анимацию команду запуска `begin="gO1.click"` при клике
  на кнопке с идентификатором `id="gO1"`
- Добавляем скрипт, который управляет остановкой анимации и запуска её
  вновь с остановленного места.

Ниже полный код приложения:

```js
let flag = 0,
    svg = document.querySelector('svg');

// Необходимо поймать второй клик (если на первом удалить атрибуты, анимация не начнётся), потом подменяем функцию на вызов по "разморозке" анимации
let start = function(){
  if(flag === 1){
    // Убираем у animateTransform триггер, чтобы не сбрасывалась анимация на ноль
    Array.from(svg.querySelectorAll('animateTransform')).forEach(e => e.removeAttribute('begin'));
    start = _ => svg.unpauseAnimations();
    start();
  }
  flag++;
}

const pause = function(){
  svg.pauseAnimations();
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
    <circle r="20" cy="20" cx="20" fill="#ce3400">
          <animateTransform  
          attributeName="transform" 
          type="translate" 
          values="0;460;0" 
    begin="gO1.click"
          dur="3s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"/> 
    </circle> 
 
   <g transform="translate(-10,60)">
      <g id="gO1" onclick='start()'>
        <rect x="45" y="85" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="#0080B8" stroke="dodgerblue" />
        <text x="62" y="102" font-size="16" fill="yellow">GO</text>
      </g>
      <g onclick='pause()'>
        <rect x="110" y="85" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="crimson" stroke="red" />
        <text x="120" y="102" font-size="16" fill="yellow">STOP</text>
      </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Скрипт и комментарии к нему не мои.  Особая благодарность @Other, который в своё время нашёл его на просторах интернета.

*Второй пример анимации отрисовки спирали*

```js
let flag = 0,
    svg = document.querySelector('svg');
let start = function(){
  if(flag === 1){
    Array.from(svg.querySelectorAll('animateMotion')).forEach(e => e.removeAttribute('begin'));
    start = _ => svg.unpauseAnimations();
    start();
  }
  flag++;
}
const pause = function(){
  svg.pauseAnimations();
}
```

```html
 <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70%" heihgt="70%" viewBox="0 150 744 1052" id="svg2" version="1">
 <path id="spiral" stroke-dashoffset="6265" stroke-dasharray="6265"  d="m351 487c0 8-11 4-14-1-6-11 4-24 15-27 19-5 37 11 40 30 4 27-18 50-44 53-35 4-64-25-66-59-3-42 32-77 73-79 50-3 90 39 92 88 2 57-46 104-102 105-65 2-117-53-119-117-1-72 60-131 131-132 80-1 144 67 145 146 1 87-74 158-160 158-95 0-171-81-171-175 0-102 88-185 190-184 110 1 198 95 197 204C557 615 456 709 340 708 215 706 115 598 117 475 119 342 233 236 364 238 504 240 616 361 614 500 611 648 484 766 337 763 182 760 58 626 61 472 65 309 206 179 367 183c170 4 306 151 302 320-4 178-158 319-335 315" fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="3">
 <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="6265;0" begin="gO1.click" dur="20s" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </path>

<circle cx="0" cy="0" r="15" fill="red" >
 <animateMotion id="an" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto-reverse" begin="gO1.click" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive">
                    <mpath xlink:href="#spiral"/>
            </animateMotion>
</circle>   
 
 <g transform="translate(-42,100)">
      <g id="gO1" onclick='start();'>
        <rect x="45" y="85" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="#0080B8" stroke="dodgerblue" />
        <text x="62" y="102" font-size="16" fill="yellow">GO</text>
      </g>
      <g onclick='pause();'>
        <rect x="110" y="85" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="crimson" stroke="red" />
        <text x="120" y="102" font-size="16" fill="yellow">STOP</text>
      </g>
    </g>
 
</svg>
```

**Третий пример анимации с `animateMotion`**

```js
let flag = 0,
    svg = document.querySelector('svg');
let start = function(){
  if(flag === 1){
    Array.from(svg.querySelectorAll('animateMotion')).forEach(e => e.removeAttribute('begin'));
    start = _ => svg.unpauseAnimations();
    start();
  }
  flag++;
}
const pause = function(){
  svg.pauseAnimations();
}
```

```html
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
width="80%" height="80%" viewBox="0 80 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >
<defs>
 <path id="Halifax" d="m0.59924304 90.492027c0 0 29.57819496 34.822463 50.33641496 40.748523 32.519562 9.28369 66.881642-13.94954 100.672832-12.5841 30.37494 1.2274 59.20656 14.18356 89.28721 18.57653 27.96955 4.08467 58.59856-4.1424 84.49327 7.19092 25.77547 11.28113 52.64841 30.50699 62.32127 56.92809 5.88571 16.07661 5.1424 38.46927-6.59167 50.93565-6.5515 6.96038-19.86195 10.13007-28.16442 5.39319-14.3782-8.20332-24.75614-32.23615-16.7788-46.74095 5.72157-10.40323 24.45669-13.69659 34.75609-7.79017 8.54871 4.90246 8.98864 28.16443 8.98864 28.16443"  fill="none" stroke="grey" />
 <path id="Montreal" d="m -18.644068,327.45763 c 0,0 50,-47.45763 51.694915,-80.08475 1.694916,-32.62712 46.250035,-33.90219 71.610173,-47.0339 38.40742,-19.88771 77.52234,-48.41729 120.76271,-47.45762 47.91599,1.06344 115.32666,29.09793 131.35593,58.47457 12.83212,23.51727 12.89881,61.90554 -6.77966,80.08475 -19.6086,18.11467 -60.92349,19.01095 -80.08475,0.42373 -20.18116,-19.57658 -20.69859,-63.21974 -2.11864,-84.32204 12.85378,-14.59876 40.7128,-14.749 58.05084,-5.9322 15.74146,8.00489 24.69348,28.21661 26.69493,45.76271 1.45817,12.7834 -1.19117,29.08693 -11.44068,36.86441 -15.87121,12.04331 -45.19359,15.30265 -59.74577,1.69491 -16.00262,-14.96405 -17.80904,-49.96379 -2.54237,-65.67796 10.03942,-10.3337 33.12482,-9.85517 43.22034,0.42373 12.07486,12.29419 11.35765,39.1192 -0.42373,51.69491 -6.58418,7.0281 -24.20393,10.57422 -28.81356,2.11864 -5.50315,-10.09461 -4.82155,-33.30802 20.76271,-27.54237 l 0,0"/>
 <path id="Calgary" d="m 432.65347,83.900354 c 0,0 -74.25173,59.645606 -115.05466,83.894026 -21.66047,12.87242 -47.63894,17.95673 -68.31371,32.35912 -21.32587,14.85596 -31.17874,46.00191 -55.7296,54.53112 -21.44134,7.44893 -54.97923,11.59821 -67.71446,-7.19092 -13.26989,-19.57794 -1.03144,-56.02328 19.17577,-68.3137 24.39964,-14.84034 67.47957,-5.99168 83.89403,17.37804 11.3655,16.18138 6.22235,45.4026 -8.3894,58.72582 -29.70449,27.08502 -95.53425,37.54029 -120.44785,5.99243 -31.850022,-40.33137 74.30061,-107.14247 43.1455,-148.01303 -19.35366,-25.388926 -70.767475,-18.378576 -95.761463,1.4825 -33.042095,26.25638 -55.9689527,89.22217 -30.508474,122.88136 15.856908,20.96311 57.894292,18.45707 78.813559,2.54237 22.902008,-17.4231 36.994628,-60.43224 20.338978,-83.8983 -13.30818,-18.74982 -49.918097,-20.12139 -68.644063,-6.77966 -20.814245,14.82957 -33.335737,54.28626 -17.79661,74.57627 11.684603,15.25701 42.223092,13.18501 57.627119,1.69491 14.994174,-11.18438 24.016704,-38.18846 14.406784,-54.23729 -8.201675,-13.69702 -33.749705,-20.47655 -46.610174,-11.01695 -8.098266,5.95673 -6.684637,24.51514 -2.118644,30.08476" style="fill:none;stroke:#000"/>   
 
  <path id="Quebec" stroke="none" fill="none" d="m 220.42163,347.7509 c 0,0 -0.44851,-49.0351 -2.0989,-98.86386 -1.431,-43.2052 3.88643,-88.98322 28.73097,-109.31338 29.64266,-24.25645 88.68863,-15.47783 114.64736,12.6168 21.62469,23.40398 24.57964,72.52926 2.1231,95.15172 -24.18791,24.36664 -79.01745,23.54947 -103.50109,-0.5257 -20.34152,-20.00217 -21.20458,-64.96515 -1.06155,-85.16342 20.63883,-20.69541 67.19752,-20.42552 88.10862,0 18.14151,17.72023 18.6938,57.48329 1.06155,75.70082 -17.27018,17.84344 -56.71261,19.09249 -74.83925,2.10279 -14.39783,-13.49477 -15.23376,-44.63362 -1.59232,-58.87841 14.00659,-14.62607 42.20404,-9.29016 61.0391,-1.57709 3.68065,1.50725 7.26981,4.74047 8.28579,8.58583 2.15892,8.17126 -6.29754,24.56042 -6.29754,24.56042"  />
  
  <path id="Saskatoon" d="m195.55354 343.27329c0 0-2.07051-68.55749-0.42012-118.38625 1.431-43.2052-3.88643-88.98322-28.73097-109.31338-29.64266-24.25645-88.68863-15.47783-114.64736 12.6168-21.62469 23.40398-24.57964 72.52926-2.1231 95.15172 24.18791 24.36664 79.01745 23.54947 103.50109-0.5257 20.34152-20.00217 21.20458-64.96515 1.06155-85.16342-20.63883-20.69541-67.19752-20.42552-88.10862 0-18.14151 17.72023-18.6938 57.48329-1.06155 75.70082 17.27018 17.84344 56.71261 19.09249 74.83925 2.10279 14.39783-13.49477 15.23376-44.63362 1.59232-58.87841-14.00659-14.62607-46.53727-15.72177-61.0391-1.57709-11.72426 11.43551-13.739284 41.01741 0.53077 48.89011 11.222462 6.19136 32.74723-20.15214 32.74723-20.15214" class="s0"/>
 
 </defs>


 <image width="400" height="400" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Yn0f.gif" /> 

<text id="Airplan" fill="gold"  font-size="24" transform="rotate(180)" >  &#9992; 
<animateMotion id="MotionHal" dur="16s" begin="gO1.click" fill="freeze" rotate="auto-reverse" repeatCount="indefinite"  >
<mpath xlink:href="#Halifax" />
</animateMotion>
</text>  

<text  fill="black"  font-size="24" transform="rotate(180)" >  &#9992; 
<animateMotion dur="16s"  begin="gO1.click" fill="freeze" rotate="auto-reverse" repeatCount="indefinite"  >
<mpath xlink:href="#Montreal" />
</animateMotion>
</text>   

<text  fill="lightcyan"  font-size="24" transform="rotate(180)" >  &#9992; 
<animateMotion dur="16s"  begin="gO1.click" fill="freeze" rotate="auto-reverse" repeatCount="indefinite"  >
<mpath xlink:href="#Calgary" />
</animateMotion>
</text> 

<text  fill="#FF00AE"  font-size="24" transform="rotate(180)" >  &#9992; 
<animateMotion dur="16s"  begin="gO1.click" fill="freeze" rotate="auto-reverse" repeatCount="indefinite"  >
<mpath xlink:href="#Quebec" />
</animateMotion>
</text> 

<text  fill="#FF00AE"  font-size="24" transform="rotate(180)" >  &#9992; 
<animateMotion dur="16s"   fill="freeze" rotate="auto-reverse" begin="gO1.click" repeatCount="indefinite"  >
<mpath xlink:href="#Saskatoon" />
</animateMotion>
</text> 
  <g transform="scale(0.75) translate(360,50)">
      <g id="gO1" onclick='start();'>
        <rect x="45" y="85" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="#0080B8" stroke="dodgerblue" />
        <text x="62" y="102" font-size="16" fill="yellow">GO</text>
      </g>
      <g onclick='pause();'>
        <rect x="110" y="85" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="crimson" stroke="red" />
        <text x="120" y="102" font-size="16" fill="yellow">STOP</text>
      </g>
    </g>
 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так, если я вас правильно понял. Вместо `<animate/>` взял свойство `animation` и добавил значение `forwards` для сохранения местоположения элемента:

```js
var circle = document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0];

function func() {
  if (this.checked = true) {
    circle.classList.toggle("animate-circle");
    circle.classList.toggle("back");
  }
}
```

```css
.animate-circle {
  animation: offsetRight 1s linear 1 forwards;
}

.back {
  animation: offsetLeft 1s linear 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes offsetRight {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(460px);
  }
}

@keyframes offsetLeft {
  from {
    transform: translateX(460px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="50">
    <circle class="animate-circle" r="20" cy="20" cx="20" fill="#ce3400"/>
</svg>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="func()">
```